# HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required PHP

Tags: php, proxy

I am working in a restricted network/limited access to internet. Since I have to use proxy to make a web service call.

Here is my PHP code from where i am calling the web service and the response .

```
$client = new SoapClient("http: //www.xyz.com/abc/wsdls/login.wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 1, 'proxy_host' => $proxy_host, 'proxy_port' => $proxy_port, 'proxy_login' => $proxy_login, 'proxy_password' => $proxy_password));
```

RESPONSE is

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.xyz.com/abc/wsdls/login.wsdl' : failed to load external entity

if I copy the url from error message and paste in browser(with same proxy settings) it works.

2nd Scenario is,
if I pass the values instead of variables it is giving me diffarant response

```
$client = new SoapClient("http: //www.xyz.com/abc/wsdls/login.wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 1, 'proxy_host' => "192.168.0.3", 'proxy_port' => 3128, 'proxy_login' => "actualuserName", 'proxy_password' => "actualPassword"));
```

> Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http:
>   //www.xyz.com/abc/wsdls/login.wsdl): failed to open stream: HTTP
>   request failed! HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required in
>   /var/www/myproj/login.php on line 56

I have passed the required proxy parameters but still getting the error.
The domain name and ip address both are listed at server/proxy settings of firewall.

Comment: Try capturing the traffic using liveheaders / iehttpheaders / wireshark. It's possibly an MSISA server insisting on using NTLM.

Comment: thanks, let me try this. To be very honest, I am unaware of this liveheader, iehttpheaders and wireshark. But I'll give my best. :)

Comment: 1 quick question, do I need to have proxy module enabled on my local apache server who is calling this web service?

Comment: no you don't need a proxy module on your apache server